# how to make footer not stretches to the full window size

Tags: css, html

I want my footer to stretches just to fit the  default `container` `width` from bootstrap. Despite it is inside a row, which in turns is within the `container` tag, it strectches to fill the whole screen width.

How to avoid it?

please check it at: https://codepen.io/jcrr1985/pen/wRKdzL

Comment: What you are asking seems kind of vauge. Why couldnt you move your footer in your container so it only expands the width of the container?

Comment: buddy, but it is inside the container...That's exactly what I'm trying to understand.. If it is inside the container tag, it should expand the width of it.

Comment: Can you give us some CSS code? Is that all the code? From what I can see, it does follow the size of the container. [Working code](https://codepen.io/tonkec/pen/oJjZKo) It might not be clear from your question what is the problem here. Btw, use ASCII HTML code for copyright, not just ©. It might not be rendered properly in some browsers. Also, why don't you use HTML semantic elements? [Read about divitis here](https://csscreator.com/divitis)

Comment: I left a codepen fot you to see it : ) ... Btw, Thanks for the advice of using ASCII HTM code.

Comment: Maybe im still confused by your question but if you want the footer to be the same width as the container why dont you make a similar class like container that uses the same breakpoints and widths? or (like I mentioend above) move your footer inside the container section? Seems like theres a lot of ways to do this. 

Also you should add your relevent code to the question and not just a codepen link.

Comment: Check again, your footer is not inside your container

Comment: https://codepen.io/IvanS95/pen/xmwdBJ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not placing the footer inside the `container` class, that fixes the issue; also, you should consider using the `<footer>` tag instead to define a page footer, instead of a `div` with a class `.footer`; try to use *semantic* tags as much as you can

```css
body{
 background-color: #E4E4E4;
}

.navbar-brand{
 font-weight: bold;
}

.form-inline input,button{
 font-size: 13px!important;
}

.barraNav{
 border: 1px solid black;
}

.section1Title{
 font-size: 26px;
}

.edit{
 background-color: #0066FF;
 border: 1px solid #00CCFF;
     padding: 5px 8px;
     border-radius: 7px;
}

.footer{
 padding: 10px;
 background-color: #666666;
 height: 75px;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
 color: #fff;

}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.4/css/tether.min.css" />
  <!--bootstrap.min.css-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <!--jquery.min.js-->
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-aOkxzJ5uQz7WBObEZcHvV5JvRW3TUc2rNPA7pe3AwnsUohiw1Vj2Rgx2KSOkF5+h" crossorigin="anonymous">
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>


    <body ng-controller = "evalController">


 <div class="wrapper">

  <div class="container">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-12">
     <div class="barraNav">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
          <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item active">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">
               <img src="logo.png">
              </a>
            </li>
            
          </ul>
          <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
            <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Buscar usuarios" aria-label="Buscar usuarios">
            <button class="btn btn-primary my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Nuevo usuario +</button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </nav>
     </div>  
    </div> 
   </div>
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-12">
     <div class="section1">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
          <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item active">
              <a class="nav-link section1Title" href="#"><strong>LISTA DE USUARIOS</strong>
               <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
              </a>
            </li>
            
          </ul>
          <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
            <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Buscar usuarios" aria-label="Buscar usuarios">
            <button class="btn btn-primary my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Nuevo usuario +</button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </nav>
     </div>  
    </div> 
   </div>

   <div class="row section2">
    <table class="table table-striped">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">Nombre de Usuario</th>
          <th scope="col">Cargo</th>
          <th scope="col">E-mail</th>
          <th scope="col">edit</th>
          <th scope="col">Password</th>
           <th scope="col">Del</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">1</th>
          <td>Mark</td>
          <td>Otto</td>
          <td><button class="edit"><i class="fas fa-pencil-alt"></i></button></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">2</th>
          <td>Jacob</td>
          <td>Thornton</td>
          <td><button class="edit"><i class="fas fa-pencil-alt"></i></button></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">3</th>
          <td>Larry</td>
          <td>the Bird</td>
          <td><button class="edit"><i class="fas fa-pencil-alt"></i></button></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>  
   </div>
  
    <footer class="row footer">
   <div class="col-12 col-sm-12">
    <span>© 2018</span>
   </div>
  </footer>
    </div> 
  
 </div>
      
 <!--Tether.min.js--> 
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.4/js/tether.min.js"></script>

 <!--bootstrap.min.js-->
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```